# How do I specify that a subdirectory is not copied during the site generation process?

Tags: r, web, r-markdown, blogdown

I have a website made with Rmarkdown that uses large data files in a data / subdirectory during its processing, but which are not necessary when displaying the html.

The builder is currently copying these files to an equivalent directory within the site / folder.

How can I specify that this data / folder is not copied during the site generation process?

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution was in the famous suggestion of many, READ THE MANUAL, but the fact is that there are many manuals and versions and I now found the vision that had what I needed.

> ```
> Site Configuration The _site.yml file has a number of options that affect site output including where it is written and what files are
> ```
>
> included and excluded from the site. Here’s an example that makes use
> of a few of these options:

```
name: "my-website"
output_dir: "_site"
include: ["import.R"]
exclude: ["docs.txt", "*.csv"]
```

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html#site-configuration